# Automatically remove a %preun broken RPM?

Tags: yum, rpm

We have an error in the `%preun` script of an RPM we distributed in the past.  This has been corrected, but, now, upgrading to the newer version is failing because the previous version is not deinstalling cleanly:

```
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package perl-perfSONAR-OPPD-MP-server
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.veW9Jb: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
error: %preun(perl-perfSONAR-OPPD-MP-server-3.4-1.pSPS.noarch) scriptlet
failed, exit status 2
```

This can be solved by uninstalling the outdated package manually without executing the `%preun` part and then reinstalling the new one:

```
rpm -e --nopreun perl-perfSONAR-OPPD-MP-server-3.4-1.pSPS.noarch
rpm -i --replacepkgs perl-perfSONAR-OPPD-MP-server-3.5-0.0.a1.pSPS.noarch.rpm
```

This is a manual procedure that requires intervention of the system administrator which we'd like to avoid.

Do someone know a way to do the same through yum so that the previous package is removed for the new one to get installed without errors, all that with a single yum command or through yum automatic upgrades?

We're using CentOS 6, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known way to automate yum upgrades with buggy scripts: yum doesn't parse nor pass the necessary disablers to rpm lib.

Comment: Would make a good plugin though

Comment: Sure would, but RPM already supports the necessary --nopreun disabler, so this isn't an RPM issue. Equally useful would be a way to mask a missing dependency rather than the way feeble --skip-broken currently implemented in yum and DNF. But I digress ... there is no known way to automate yum/dnf upgrades with broken %preun scripts at the moment.